# pcap_open_live not found in -lpcap

Tags: linux, ubuntu, libpcap

I am trying to build [reaver](http://code.google.com/p/reaver-wps/downloads/detail?name=reaver-1.4.tar.gz&can=2&q=) on Ubuntu 12.04 32bit. I have already built and installed [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/#latest-release).

Running `./configure`, I get following error:

> checking for pcap_open_live in -lpcap... no
>
> error: pcap library not found!

Any help in fixing this is highly appreciated.

**EDIT:** This is the check in configure script:

```
{ $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: checking for pcap_open_live in -lpcap" >&5

$as_echo_n "checking for pcap_open_live in -lpcap... " >&6; }

if test "${ac_cv_lib_pcap_pcap_open_live+set}" = set; then :

  $as_echo_n "(cached) " >&6

else

  ac_check_lib_save_LIBS=$LIBS
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need more libraries, take a look at this [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/reaver-wps/issues/detail?id=97):

Looks like you need (as odd as it sounds):

```
sudo apt-get install libpcap-dev sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
```

Comment: Thanks...It solved the problem. Thought I still can't believe this could be the solution!

Comment: I also needed libpcap-dev. In short: `sudo apt-get install libpcap-dev sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev`